# redis store 128 bit number

Tags: redis, ipv6, subnet, int128

I want to efficiently search **IPv6 subnet range using redis**.

i thought of storing the IPv6 numeric addresses in redis and search them by range.
those are **128-bit ints**, e.g:

```
import ipaddress
int(ipaddress.ip_address(u'113f:a:2:3:4:1::77'))

> 22923991422715307029586104612626104439L
```

and query by range:

```
ZRANGEBYSCORE numerics <subnet-S-start> <subnet-S-end>
```

**HOWEVER**, redis sorted-sets can hold score of up to 2^53, so all my large ints are being trimmed and I'm losing precision.

Is there a way to save such large numbers in redis without losing precision?

Do you have a better suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: You may want to convert that number to a byte array and save that instead

Comment: Redis may not be the right tool for the job. Postgres, as an example, has robust, native support for IPv4 and IPv6 datatypes.

Comment: @tadman redis is ideal for this, but as usual with redis a little bit of work is required.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the lexical range API, it will suit you exactly. https://redis.io/commands/zrangebylex

Insert the addresses with a score of 0, I don't even think you need to encode them as numbers, just pad the individual bytes, and you should be able to query an range.

Comment: For some answers, like the above, I want to have more than one upvote to give :)

Comment: @Not_a_Golfer could you elaborate on this just a little more? I am trying to implement something similar but having more trouble than expected.